# How to get the Client IP that request a Tor WebPage?

Tags: php, html, ip, ip-address, tor

i'm running an hidden service as the final exam of my school, but i've a problem:  i have to show that the IP of the same computer which connects to my website can change in a bit , but when i try functions such as `$ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];` it always gives me 127.0.0.1 instead of the last tor node which connects to me.
How can i solve this ? Is it normal on the Tor network? Cheers in advance!

Comment: Hiding the real ip of the computer connecting to you is the entire point of Tor!

Comment: It's normal for TOR to show `127.0.0.1` as TOR is run via you localhost. You could check the followup IP if that gives you more information, but you'll probably only get the next hop.

Comment: I mean, i would know the last tor node IP which connects to me ( which should change every time somebody connects), but it always gives me 127.0.0.1 ! Isn't a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

There is a no direct way , but you can try using a third party server to get actual ip even from localhost server.

```
 <?php         
    $content = file_get_contents('http://checkip.dyndns.com/');
    preg_match('/Current IP Address: \[?([:.0-9a-fA-F]+)\]?/', $content, $ip);
    echo $externalIp = $ip[1];
 ?>
```

Here is a working [PHPFiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/0k49-pqjy) . Hope this will help, cheers :)

Comment: Looks like this doesn't work at all, i just wrote down the code you put here and then put an `echo" $externalIp"` ... but nothing appear

Comment: Here is an working [PHPFiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/0k49-pqjy)